# Sharepoint 2013 Search Event Viewer log messages are not English?

Tags: search, enterprise-search, language, language-pack

The Event Viewer log messages are in Chinese (or occasionally Thai on other servers).  The server default is English, and all other log entries are English.

- Applications and services logs\Microsoft\Office Server\Search

Log title and messages are all in an incorrect language.[image]

Example (log title):

Comment: Did you install a chinese language pack? Maybe before provisioning search?

Comment: There's multiple language packs installed, and they may have been installed before search (the entire solution is installed via AutoSPInstall). Unfortunately at this stage I'm not sure of the install order.